# Conditionally show table column headings

Tags: conditional, table-field

Is there a way to conditionally display a table column heading if the table field row has been entered? i.e.

if my table has up to 3 columns
and I fill in ALL the fields like this I'd see

### ch1 | ch2 | ch3

a   |  b  |  c

but, if I only fill in 2 columns without conditionals I'd see this

### ch1 | ch2 | ch3

a   |  b  |

I'd like to conditionally only show the column headings/rows populated like this:

### ch1 | ch2 |

a   |  b  |

Is that possible?

Comment: Can't you just loop through your table and check if the rows are set and if not you don't display the headline? That's what we do in this case

Comment: Thanks yeap got this sorted like that and with some variables `{% set showCol1 = false %}` having discussed with another dev

Comment: @KevN - go ahead and add this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
{% set showCol1 = false %}
{% set showCol2 = false %}
{% set showCol3 = false %}
{% set showCol4 = false %}
{% set showCol5 = false %}


{% for row in entry.fieldname %}
{% if row.col1|length %}{% set showCol1 = true %}{% endif %}
{% if row.col2|length %}{% set showCol2 = true %}{% endif %}
{% if row.col3|length %}{% set showCol3 = true %}{% endif %}
{% if row.col4|length %}{% set showCol4 = true %}{% endif %}
{% if row.col5|length %}{% set showCol5 = true %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}


<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        {% if showCol1 %}<th>Col 1</th>{% endif %}
        {% if showCol2 %}<th>Col 2</th>{% endif %}
        {% if showCol3 %}<th>Col 3</th>{% endif %}
        {% if showCol4 %}<th>Col 4</th>{% endif %}
        {% if showCol5 %}<th>Col 5</th>{% endif %}
    </tr>
</thead>
{% for row in entry.fieldname %}
    <tr>
        {% if showCol1 %}<td>{{ row.col1 }}</td>{% endif %}
        {% if showCol2 %}<td>{{ row.col2 }}</td>{% endif %}
        {% if showCol3 %}<td>{{ row.col3 }}</td>{% endif %}
        {% if showCol4 %}<td>{{ row.col4 }}</td>{% endif %}
        {% if showCol5 %}<td>{{ row.col5 }}</td>{% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this challenge too and ended up solving it slightly differently:

```twig
{% set columnsToShow = [] %}
{% set tableField = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('tableFieldHandle') %}

{% for row in entry.tableFieldHandle %}
    {% for column in tableField.settings.columns|filter(column => row[column.handle] and column.handle not in columnsToShow) %}
        {% set columnsToShow = columnsToShow|push(column.handle) %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for column in tableField.settings.columns|filter(column => column.handle in columnsToShow) %}
                <th>{{ column.heading }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in entry.tableFieldHandle %}
            <tr>
                {% for column in tableField.settings.columns|filter(column => column.handle in columnsToShow) %}
                    <td>{{ row[column.handle] }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It does the same thing as your answer, but it's a bit more concise, and this way you don't need to edit the template code if you add any new columns.

Edit to add: if you ever need to do this from the context of a table inside a matrix block instead of a simple table field, you can create the array like this, where `table` is the handle of the block type and you already have a reference to the current `block`:

```twig
{% set columnsToShow = [] %}
{% set tableColumns = block.fieldLayout.fields|filter(field => field.handle == 'table')|first.columns %}

{% for row in block.table %}
    {% for column in tableColumns|filter(column => row[column.handle] and column.handle not in columnsToShow) %}
        {% set columnsToShow = columnsToShow|push(column.handle) %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```